# CSS Opacity causes behavior like position:fixed in Chrome

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a pagination: when the nextpage > totalpages I don't provide a link and attempt to visually inform the user that its an invalid link. For this, I originally used bootstrap's 'disabled' class.

However when I would scroll the page, that particular button remains stationary on the screen (like position:fixed). I checked all the CSS but the only difference I could find was Opacity:0.4.

I created a custom class to use instead of bootstrap's 'disabled', and the only option I included was Opacity:0.4. If I set Opacity:1, there is no issue. If I change Opacity to a decimal, the element scrolls with the page.

I don't think this was an intended feature, and I'm not sure why its happening. Anyone have any clues to what could be causing the error?

Sample pagination output (ignore the poor formatting please)

```css
.navDisabled {
  opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='form-inline'>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <label>Number Per Page <select class='form-control' id="nppDropdown"><option value="5">5</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="50">50</option></select></label>
  </div>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
      <ul class='pagination'>

        <li><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></li>

        <li><span>1</span></li>

        <li class='next navDisabled'><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

One last thing: This is only happening in Chrome. I tested in Firefox and there are no issues.

edit -----

I resolved this issue by applying the navDisabled class to the inner element (span) instead of the li element. Bootstrap documentation (quoted below) says to put it on the li, but that apparently causes problems in chrome.

> [Bootstrap 3.0 Documentation for Pagination](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination)

```
<nav aria-label="...">
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="previous disabled"><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Older</a></li>
    <li class="next"><a href="#">Newer <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you please create a **runnable**, **inspectable** [mcve]?

Comment: I resolved this issue, see my edit.